# Adding data to nested collection firebase cloud firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Right now my firebase cloud firestore looks like this:

[image]

```
const db = fire.firestore();       

db.collection("groupFavs/"+groupID+ "/"+currentUserUID).add({favs: likedData})
```

The code above creates a collection called groupFavs, a document called groupID and another collection with the current users id. In the image I have above, it keeps creating documents for the users likes when i just want the currentuser id to only have one list in it which will be all their liked data. But instead it just keeps making multiple of them and I think its because of .add

I've tried using set but that wont work. Where am I going wrong?

```
 db.collection("groupFavs2")
    .doc(groupID).collection(currentUserUID)
     .set({
       favs: likedData
     })
```

I basically want to do something like this above but my logic is off in regards to the nested collection because what im calling above does not work

Comment: Are you trying to update existing userID document instead of creating a new one everytime ?

Comment: If you want to keep all the like data in map, you should not update the collection, you have to update the map with in the document, in above code you are adding doc in collection, you need to go into * collection-document-map-(and now update the required/or add new data while keeping the old one, search for it , I have done it once.

Comment: Did the solution I provided solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can circumvent the string concatenation as well as the nested `.collection` `.doc` chain by using string interpolation as follows:

```js
const collectionRef = db.collection(`groupFavs/${groupID}/${currentUserUID}`)

collectionRef.add({favs: likedData})
```

In regards to the multiple documents, you are adding a new document under the sub collection (matching the users id). Ideally this would look something like this:

- Group Favs

  - 1st UserId

    - Like 1 doc
    - Like 2 doc
  - 2st UserId

    - Like 1 doc
    - Like 2 doc

Where the `like doc` can contain information related to the like such as image or liked boolean property.

If instead what you would like to do is keep a list of the users likes under their doc you can do it as follows:

```
const docRef= db.doc(`groupFavs/${groupID}/${currentUserUID}`)

const newLikeData = {
likes: firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(<your_like_information>)
}

docRef.set({favs: likedData}, {merge:true})
```

`arrayUnion` will append whatever data is in <your_like_information>.

Alternatively, you could query for the current likes list under the users doc, manually append the information and pass the entire object to a update or setDoc with merge: true.